# java construct method definition

Tags: java, methods, constructor

What is this called?
This is a constructor from the `Bits` class from JBitTorrent API. It is perfectly valid:

```
public Bits and(Bits b){ /* something */ }
```

But there's a space in the method name. So whas is this called? I thought is "java multimethod" but it's not.

Comment: It would be valid if `}` was on its own line or `//something` was `/*something*/`.

Comment: @BoltClock: *and* it would actually have a `return` statement ... but that's beside the point, as the method body is obviously not the focus of this question.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a constructor, it's a regular Java method.

The first `Bits` is the return type, and `and` is the method name.

If it were a constructor, it would not have a return type, and the name would be the name of the class it is constructing.

The method *may be* constructing a new `Bits` instance and returning it, but it's still a method.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a constructor and there's no space in the method name.

The method is called `and`, it takes a `Bits` object as the argument and it returns a `Bits` object.

It's a normal method with there's no particular name for this (from the language perspective).

It's a common pattern, usually used for immutable objects: instead of modifying the object on which the method is called, a new object is created with the modified state (this can also be done on mutable objects, but is more common with immutable ones).

Answer (score 1):

Where do you think you see a space in the method name?

```
public Bits and(Bits b){ //something }
```

It is a `public` method named `and` that returns a `Bits` object, and that takes a `Bits` object as an argument (with the argument variable named `b`).

It is not a constructor, just a regular method.

Answer (score 1):

> but there's a space in the method name

No there isn't. The method name is "and". `Bits` is the return type!

Answer (score 1):

There's not a space in the method, the method name is "and".

- **`public`** - modifier
- **`Bits`** - return value
- **`and`** - method name
- **`Bits b`** - a parameter b of type Bits

Answer (score 1):

Usually used in a [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) (e.g. [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)) where fields/operations are provided to create a fully constructed object.

The `public Bits and(Bits b) {...}` is not a constructor but method that requires a `Bits b` in order to change the state of the current internal bits (ANDed).

The implementation would be of this effect.

```
public Bits and(Bits b) {
    this.doAnd(b);

    //Now that our internal bits are ANDed with bits B, return our changed state
    return this;
}
```